# DataClassesDatacontext Stackoverflow when submitting changes

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I am currently trying to update values in my Database. My code worked flawlessly until I've added a new value to the Database. I have updated my DataClasses1.dbml and it shows the new column I have added to the Database. Still I am getting a Stackoverflowexception when context.SubmitChanges() gets called. The ChangeSet contains 2 Objects which should be updated (update 5 columns per row in this case)

```
            var customers = new List<Customer>();
            using (var context = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var result = from custs in context.Customer
                             where custs.ACTION_ID == desRequest.First().ACTION_ID &&
                                    !custs.ARCHIVATED
                             select custs;

                Inputvalidation.SetAddressLines(ref result);
                context.SubmitChanges();
                customers = result.ToList();
            }
```

context.GetChangeSet shows:

```
{{Inserts: 0, Deletes: 0, Updates: 2}}
    Deletes: Count = 0
    Inserts: Count = 0
    Updates: Count = 2
```

Before the update of each row I'm adding new customers from a json-post in nancyfx with this code (which to my surprise still works as intended)

```
    private static bool AddItems(string request)
    {
        // Hier alle sammeln und in einem wisch rein
        var customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Customer>>(request);
        foreach (var cstmr in customers)
        {
            using (var context = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                context.Customer.InsertOnSubmit(cstmr);
                try
                {
                    context.SubmitChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //TODO: Hier ggfs. reparieren
                    context.SubmitChanges();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

These are the error-details: [image: These are the error-]
"Das Programm "[8028] iisexpress.exe" wurde mit Code -2147023895 (0x800703e9) beendet."

The Stacktrace shows null.
What am I doing wrong and what can I improve?

Comment: What is the stack trace of your exception? That tends to help a lot with stack overflow exceptions.

Comment: There is no additional information in the Error-Details. I've updated the OP

Comment: OK, it seems the system crashes so profoundly that it can not give you the stack. If the system pauses for a while until crash, you can pause in the debugger and check the call stack. That might give you a hint what's happening.

Comment: Sadly it just flatout dies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted the "obj" Folder of my Solution and rebuilt the Project and everything works as intended again.